# Plotting discrete data but not using discreteplot function

Tags: plotting

For a given function:

```
Plot[Sqrt[Abs[x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

I have the code to draw the function (with its Abs remove), partial sums and cesaro means as:

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[x]
s[k_, x_] := \frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{3}+(-Sqrt[2] FresnelS[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n]] + 2 Sqrt[n] Sin[n \[Pi]])/(n^(3/2) Sqrt[\[Pi]]) Cos[n x], {n, 1, k}] 
partialsums[x_] = Table[s[n, x], {n, {4}}]; 
c[n_, x_] := (1/n) Sum[s[m, x], {m, 0, n - 1}]
Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], partialsums[x], c[4, x]}], {x, -Pi, Pi},
PlotLegends -> {"f(x)=x", "Fourier, 4 terms", "Cesaro, 4 terms"}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Dashed, Thickness[0.006]}, {Red, Thickness[0.006]}}]
```

This code fails on my computer and hence I resolve to manual computation.

Updates: It turn out that I can easily solve this issue by removing the k with any number rather than letting it to be indefinite. Although I am not certain the graph is right for k=4 as both graphs(Partial and Cesaro) coincides with each other.

Comment: You can use `Show` to combine different plots.

Comment: All the integrals you list for $n=1,2,\ldots,5$ are *zero*: you seem to be displaying some kind of floating point error.  They are not relevant to the $a_n$ anyway.  So what *really* is your question?

Comment: Thank you for changing those erroneous values--although the integrands are now incorrect, because they omit most of the function. (However, I do not understand why you need "manual computation" when you have already exhibited a valid *Mathematica* formula for computing the $a_n$.) I also do not understand what you mean by a "continuous" graph to "contain" these *discrete* values. An example or a sketch might help convey your intentions.

Comment: @whuber: I had re-edited the post. Do let me know if it is not clear and I will try to improve it again.

Comment: I'm still lost: $a_n$ defines a *sequence* $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n, \ldots$. It is inherently discrete. What "smooth curve" are you hoping to draw with this sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
plt = Plot[f[k], {k, 0, 50}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red,ImageSize -> 300];
dplt = DiscretePlot[cesaro[k], {k, 0, 50}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> PlotRange[plt],
PlotStyle -> Directive[{Blue, Dashed}], Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 300]; 
Row[{plt, dplt, Show[plt, dplt]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** or, perhaps, this:?

```
 dplt2 = DiscretePlot[cesaro[k], {k, 0, 50}, Frame -> True, Filling -> None, 
 PlotRange -> PlotRange[plt], PlotStyle -> Blue, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 300];
 Row[{plt, dplt2, Show[plt, dplt2]}]
```

[image]

or, using `Interpolation` on `cesaro[k]` and

```
 intFCsr = Interpolation[Table[{k, cesaro[k]}, {k, 0, 50}]];
 Plot[{f[k], intFCsr[k]}, {k, 0, 50}, Frame -> True,PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

**Update 2:**

```
 intFCsr = Interpolation[Table[{k, cesaro[k]}, {k, 0, 50}]];
 intFPrtlSms = Interpolation[Table[{k, part[k]}, {k, 0, 50}]];
 Plot[{f[k], intFCsr[k], intFPrtlSms[k]/15}, {k, 0, 50},  ImagePadding -> 45,
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Black}, ImageSize -> 500,
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["f, cesaro", 12], Style["partial sum", 12]},
   {Style["k", 12], Style["plot label", 14]}},
 FrameTicks -> {{Join[{#, #, {.01, 0}} & /@ Range[0, 4.],
   {#, " ", {.0075, 0}} & /@ Range[0.2, 4., .2]],
  Join[{#, 15 #, {.01, 0}} & /@ Range[0, 4.],
    {#, " ", {.0075, 0}} & /@ Range[0.2, 4., .2]]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, this edited version looks good! Now that you had inserted the cesaro means graph, do you think it is possible to combine the partial sums graph into it so that there are altogether three graphs? The function as shown in the diagram is in red while the cesaro is in blue. Perhaps we can have the partial sums line as black if possible. I look forward to your help kguler. Amazing updates indeed.

Comment: @Sandra, does this give what you need: `intFPrtlSms = Interpolation[Table[{k, part[k]}, {k, 0, 50}]];
Plot[{f[k], intFCsr[k], intFPrtlSms[k]}, {k, 0, 50},
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Black}]`?

Comment: Amazing! May I know why are the labels "f,cesaro" on the left of y axis while "partial sum" on the right hand side of y-axis? When I use Plot function, I plot all diagrams based on x-axis. I am not sure if the two graph of cesaro and the partial is correct but I am certain the function graph is correct.

Comment: @Sandra, if you use `f` and the interpolated versions of your `cesaro` and `part` functions in the same plot (`Plot[{f[k], intFCsr[k], intFPrtlSms[k]}, {k, 0, 50}, 
 ImagePadding -> 45, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Black},  ImageSize -> 500]`) gives a graph in which the details of `f` and `cesaro` are not visible because their vertical scale is much smaller then that of `part` - hence two different vertical scales.

Comment: thank you so much for these changes and explanation. I had voted this as the answer and thank you!